# Reset one trigger in jquery after switching pages in pagination JSON

Tags: jquery

I have a bootstrap table with pagination and I use a `mouseover` event that is triggered with `.one` when the user moves their mouse over the table for an x-editable plugin.

The `mouseover` event works when I first load the table just fine. As soon as I go to the next page the `mouseover` event does not work anymore because of it already being triggered from the first page. Is it possible to reset the `.one` trigger after switching pages so it only fires once every page and not just once overall.

**JS Table**

```
var $table = $('#table-javascript').bootstrapTable({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'bootstrap_database.php',
    height: 2500,
    cache: false,
    striped: true,
    pagination: true,
    search: true,
    pageSize: 200,
    pageList: [200, 400, 1000, 2000],
    minimumCountColumns: 2,
    clickToSelect: true,
    columns: [{
        field: 'ID',
        title: 'ID',
        align: 'center',
        visible: false
    },{
        field: 'backlink',
        title: 'Backlink',
        align: 'left',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'indexed',
        title: 'PI',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'dindexed',
        title: 'DI',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
    },{
        field: 'email',
        title: 'Email',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'social',
        title: 'Social+',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'whois',
        title: 'Whois+',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'notes',
        title: 'Notes',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'removed',
        title: '<i class="fa fa-chain"></i> Removed',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'import_label',
        title: 'Label',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'important',
        title: '<i class="fa fa-eye fa-2x"></i>',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20'
    },{
        field: 'refresh',
        title: 'Refresh',
        align: 'center',
        width: '20',
        class: 'refreshstats'
    }]
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="table-javascript"></div>
```

**x-editable code**

```
$('#table-javascript').one('mousemove', function() {
    $('.email').on('mouseover', function() {
        var thislink = $(this).attr('data-value');
        $.fn.editableform.buttons  = '<a href="mailto:'+thislink+'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#table-javascript').on('mouseover', '.email', function() {
    var thislink = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $.fn.editableform.buttons  = '<a href="mailto:'+thislink+'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>';
});
```